# Clarification of web deploy project settings

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, msbuild, webdeploy

During a web deployment I'd like to change some ACL settings.  I found [this article](http://leethams.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/modifying-directory-permissions-with-web-deployment/) describing the process.

The article includes the following code snippet:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!- Extends the AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest 
        action to also set ACLs–>
    <IncludeCustomACLs>TRUE</IncludeCustomACLs>

    <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest Condition=“‘$(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest)’==”“>
        $(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest);
        SetCustomACLs;
    </AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My question relates to the *Condition* attribute.  From the comment, it appears that the intent is to append *SetCustomACLs* to the *AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest* property.  But from the condition, it appears that this block is only evaluated when *AAISAFCTSM* is not already set, so this isn't an "extension" so much as a "set-if-null".

So do the comment and markup disagree, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Condition is there to ensure that if you've set AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest somewhere else in the build stack explicitly, then it wont be altered.  Having said that, I'd say that you aren't missing something, it reads to me the exact same way it reads to you.